# Applying function to a list of values in Pandas row, why am I only getting first result?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data frame that consists of two columns and I would like to clean the second column 'tweets'. Each value in the second column 'tweets' consists of a list that contains ~ 100 items.

I would like to iterate through each list in each row to clean the text.

A sample of my data frame (each item in the lists is a string with quotes):

```
data = ({'user_id':['324','242'],
     'tweets':[["NEWS FLASH: popcorn-flavored Tic-Tacs taste as crap as you imagine.",
                 "The 1970s is here to show us the way: https:xxxx",
                 "FB needs to hurry up and add a laugh/cry button üò¨üò≠üòìü§¢üôÑüò±"],
               ["You don't feel like hiding in your personal cave quite so much",
                "More for Cancer https://xxxx",
                "You prefer to keep things to yourself today"]]})
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I wrote this regex to remove `http tags`:

```
#function to remove HTML tags 
def remove_html(mylist):
    for item in mylist:
        text =re.sub(r'http\S+','',item,flags=re.MULTILINE)
        return text
```

and I applied to each row in the data frame using this code:

```
df['tweets']=df['tweets'].apply(remove_html)
```

the problem is that when I apply the function to the data frame, I only get the first element in each list. For some reason, the function only returns the first element.

The output I get:

```
0    NEWS FLASH: popcorn-flavored Tic-Tacs taste as crap as you imagine.
1    You don't feel like hiding in your personal cave quite so much     
Name: tweets, dtype: object
```

Any tip would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `remove_html()` function.
You're returning early, and only the first element of the list.
Use the function below, and notice how the `return` statement is outside of the `for` loop.

```
def remove_html(mylist): 
    return_list = [] 
    for item in mylist: 
        text = re.sub(r'http\S+','',item,flags=re.MULTILINE) 
        return_list.append(text)  
    return return_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `remove_html` returns only the first element.

You can try the following code instead.

```py
#function to remove HTML tags 
def remove_html(mylist):
    t = []
    for item in mylist:
        text =re.sub(r'http\S+','',item,flags=re.MULTILINE)
        t.append(text)
    return t
```